# Changing screen through an if condition in Kivy does not seem to work

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to create a button that moves to the next screen when all the spinners have values that are selected. To identify when the spinners have values (The day, hour and minute spinners), I have assigned values for `state` for each of the spinners. Most of the code works as expected, except for the if statement in the kv code I have shown below.

```
    Button:
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    size: (400, 130)
    size_hint: (None, None)
    pos_hint: {'right': 0.6, 'center_y': 0}
    on_press:
        root.hours_checking()
        if day.state == hours.state == minutes.state == AmPm.state == 'True': \
        root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
```

This is the part of the code that doesn't seem to execute for some reason. The transition to screen 3 doesn't occur.

> ```
>         if day.state == hours.state == minutes.state == AmPm.state == 'True': \
>         root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
> ```

```
Spinner:
    id: day
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 44
    pos_hint: {'center': (.5, .5)}
    text: 'Day'
    values: 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'
    on_text:
        root.on_day_select(self.text)
        state: 'True'
Spinner:
    id: hours
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 44
    pos_hint: {'center': (.1, .5)}
    text: 'Hour'
    values: '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'
    on_text:
        root.on_hours_select(self.text)
        state: 'True'
Spinner:
    id: minutes
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 44
    pos_hint: {'center': (.3, .5)}
    text: 'Minutes'
    values: '00', '15', '30', '45'
    on_text:
        root.on_minutes_select(self.text)
        state: 'True'
Spinner:
    id: AmPm
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 44
    pos_hint: {'center': (.4, .5)}
    text: 'AM/PM'
    values: 'a.m', 'p.m'
    on_text:
        root.on_AmPm_select(self.text)
        state: 'True'
```

Here is my whole code. If it helps solve my error.

```
    import kivy

kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

# You can create your kv code in the Python file
Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenOne>:
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                source: 'back1.jpg'
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            on_press:
                # You can define the duration of the change
                # and the direction of the slide
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'

    BoxLayout: 
        Label:
            id: blinky
            text: "Click Anywhere To Continue"
            font_size: '20sp'
            font_name: "Raleway-Regular"
            size_hint: (1.0, 0)
            alpha: 1
            color: (1, 1, 1, self.alpha)


<ScreenTwo>:
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                source: 'back2.jpg'
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos 
        Label:
            id: white_box
            size: (500,500)
            alpha: 1
            bcolor: (1, 1, 1, self.alpha)
        Button:
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            size: (400, 130)
            size_hint: (None, None)
            pos_hint: {'right': 0.6, 'center_y': 0.30}
            on_press:
                root.time_now()
                root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
        Button:
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            size: (400, 130)
            size_hint: (None, None)
            pos_hint: {'right': 0.6, 'center_y': 0}
            on_press:
                root.hours_checking()
                if day.state == hours.state == minutes.state == AmPm.state == 'True': \
                root.manager.current = 'screen_three' 
        Spinner:
            id: day
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 44
            pos_hint: {'center': (.5, .5)}
            text: 'Day'
            values: 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'
            on_text:
                root.on_day_select(self.text)
                self.state: 'True'
        Spinner:
            id: hours
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 44
            pos_hint: {'center': (.1, .5)}
            text: 'Hour'
            values: '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'
            on_text:
                root.on_hours_select(self.text)
                self.state: 'True'
        Spinner:
            id: minutes
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 44
            pos_hint: {'center': (.3, .5)}
            text: 'Minutes'
            values: '00', '15', '30', '45'
            on_text:
                root.on_minutes_select(self.text)
                self.state: 'True'
        Spinner:
            id: AmPm
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 44
            pos_hint: {'center': (.4, .5)}
            text: 'AM/PM'
            values: 'a.m', 'p.m'
            on_text:
                root.on_AmPm_select(self.text)
                self.state: 'True'

<ScreenThree>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            on_press:
                # You can define the duration of the change
                # and the direction of the slide
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'
""")

# Create a class for all screens in which you can include
# helpful methods specific to that screen
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')  # 0 being off 1 being on as in true/false
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '960')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        super(ScreenTwo, self).__init__()
        self.state = state
    def time_now(self):
        global now, month_now, date_now, day_now, hour_now, minute_now, time_now
        now = datetime.now()
        print(now)

        month_now = int(now.strftime("%m"))  # month in int
        print("month:", month_now)

        date_now = int(now.strftime("%d"))  # date in int
        print("date:", date_now)

        day_now = now.strftime("%A")  # day in str
        print("day of the week:", day_now)

        hour_now = int(now.strftime("%H")) * 100
        minute_now = int(now.strftime("%M"))
        time_now = hour_now + minute_now  # day in str in 24 hour format
        print("time:", time_now)

    def check_open(day_now, opening_days, time_now, opening_time):
        global isopen
        opening_days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Saturday"]
        opening_time = [800, 2200]
        isopen = False
        if day_now in opening_days and time_now >= opening_time[0] and time_now <= opening_time[1]:
            isopen = True
            print("Is the store open? ", isopen)
            return isopen
        else:
            print("Is the store open? ", isopen)
            return
    def on_day_select(self, text):
        global day
        day = str(text)
    def on_hours_select(self, text):
        global hours
        hours = int(text)
    def on_minutes_select(self, text):
        global minutes
        minutes = int(text)
    def on_AmPm_select(self,text):
        global AmPm
        AmPm = str(text)
    def hours_checking(self):
        global AmPm
        global hours
        global minutes
        global day
        try:
            if 1 <= hours <= 11 and AmPm == 'a.m':
                pass
            elif 1 <= hours <= 12 and AmPm == 'p.m':
                hours += 12
            elif hours == 12 and AmPm == 'a.m':
                hours = 0
        except:
            print('error')
        else:
            print(day, hours, minutes)

    pass


class ScreenThree(Screen):
    pass


# The ScreenManager controls moving between screens
screen_manager = ScreenManager()

# Add the screens to the manager and then supply a name
# that is used to switch screens
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name="screen_one"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name="screen_two"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenThree(name="screen_three"))


class KivyTut2App(App):
    def blink_animation(self, dt):
        anim = Animation(alpha=0, duration=1) + Animation(alpha=1, duration=1)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(screen_manager.get_screen('screen_one').ids.blinky)

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.blink_animation)
        return screen_manager


sample_app = KivyTut2App()
sample_app.run()
```

Comment: Why in the `if` you check for equality with 1 but the state gets `True`?

Comment: I copy-pasted an older version of the code, my bad. But it doesn't work with 'True' either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
on_text:
    root.on_day_select(self.text)
    state: 'True'
```

The `state: True` part of this doesn't do anything useful. I assume you're using Python 3 and so this is being parsed as an [annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/).

You probably want to use `self.state = True`. This still won't work unless you've defined a `state` property on the class (which you probably haven't), and also because your `if day.state == hours.state == minutes.state == AmPm.state == 1` is checking for the value 1, not the value `'True'` which is a string.

Comment: I've tried adding a property to my class
 
`class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        super(ScreenTwo, self).__init__()
        self.state = state`

However, now I get the error ` TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'` Could you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I've also posted the rest of my code above. If that helps.

Comment: You still didn't fix the problem of using `self.state: 'True'` you need to *set* the value using `self.state = 'True'`.

Comment: Also your setting `self.state` in the Screen class doesn't do anything useful, since you never access that. It is the state attribute of the Spinners that you are setting/changing.

Comment: I apologize if my questions sound stupid, as I'm very new to Kivy and OOP. Could you explain where I need to set my value using `self.state: 'True'` as I've changed those under each of the spinners in my new code. Additionally, I'm not sure where to define the state property is it's not useful defining under the class Screen 2.

Comment: You *don't* need to set your value using `self.state: 'True'`, that's the opposite of what I said.

Comment: I suggest making a minimal example demonstrating your problem with as little code as possible, then asking about that. It's much easier to correct a shorter code sample.